# How to write a simple markdown (syntax) highlighter from scratch with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, markdown

I want to create a simple and fast markdown highlighter with javascript.

Input:

```
This is a **test bold** and __italic__ markdown.
```

Output (HTML):

```
This is a <b>**test bold**</b> and <i>__italic__</i> markdown.
```

Comment: @NinaScholz Is `data = data.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, '<b>**$1**</b>');` best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answer is best practice and the fastest way:

```
let data = 'This is a **test bold** and __italic__ markdown.';
data = data.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, '<b>**$1**</b>');
data = data.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, '<i>__$1__</i>');
```